# Finding Work Done

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the work done by F=yi+xj in a moving particle from (-1,0) to (0,0) along the curve y = e^xy - 1.

So far I found the change in position of the particle to be (1,0) and I know the equation for Work is F*dR I have F = yi+xj but would you be multiplying that by the (1,0)? since that technically is the change in position?